# Javascript: Question Not being displayed and message when correctly answered or incorrectly answer

Tags: javascript

In my program, it is supposed to generate 2 random numbers and then the user asked what number do you get if you multiply the numbers. When I tried running it, it does not display the part of the question which tells you what the equation is. I debugged it, but it does not show any issues. I was wondering if anyone can tell me how to solve my problem. I am sorry about any inconvenience, I am new to javascript, so I really need help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunctions()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
      function myFunctions() {
        let random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        let random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        let answer = random1 * random2;
        let counter = 0;
        let max = 5;
        while (attempts != answer) {
          var attempts = prompt('Please answer what is', random1, '*', random2);
          counter += 1;
          if (counter > max) {
            console.log(
              'You have no more tries left.',
              'The answer was',
              answer,
              '.'
            );
          }
          if (attempts == answer) {
            console.log(
              'Congrats the number was',
              answer,
              'and it took you',
              counter,
              'tries!'
            );
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(myFunctions);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You asked this before, I see you've made changes - what does the code do that you don't expect?

Comment: prompt takes two arguments ... the prompt text and a default value ... you're passing in 4 arguments - as I suggested last time `prompt(\`Please answer what is ${random1} * ${random2}\`);`

Comment: you'll also want a `break` in the `if (counter > max) {` block

Comment: @Bravo Thanks, you fixed one of my issues. The only other issues are that it does not display the message if the user answers the question correctly or when the user answers the question incorrectly 5 times.

Comment: because your while loop never "break"s

Comment: @Bravo Any tips on how to break the loop? I can't find a way

Comment: kind of like *you'll also want a break in the if (counter > max) { block* comment from an hour ago?

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be like this:

The prompt function has 2 params, the first is required which is the text to display, the second is optional (default text).

also do not use ',' in console.log function to concatenate strings.

```
 function myFunctions() {
                let random1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                let random2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                let answer = random1 * random2;
                let counter = 0;
                let max = 5;
                while (attempts != answer) {
                    var attempts = prompt("Please answer what is " + random1 + " * " + random2);
                    counter += 1;
                    if (counter > max) {
                        console.log("You have no more tries left. The answer was" + answer +".");
                        break;
                    }
                    if (attempts == answer) {
                        console.log("Congrats the number was " + answer +  " and it took you " + counter + " tries!");
                    }
    
                }
    
            }
```

Good luck!